# Gnome3 memory comsuption high

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, gnome-shell

I recently installed ArchLinux on my desktop.

I simply installed the base system and installed GNOME and GDM and the system work "fine". However today (after 10 hours) when I tried to open any application the system now tells me that it can't do it because the memory is full.

Comment: What do commands such as `free` report?

Comment: less than 50M free

Comment: Can you include the output of the command `free`? The results can be misleading.

Comment: Here's a snippet from [commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3/display-the-top-ten-running-processes-sorted-by-memory-usage) that will display the top 10 memory-consuming processes: `ps aux | sort -nk +4 | tail`. Does it help pinopint the culprit process(es)?

Comment: yah i have a similar command for that. and for now the shell are using 176M but this morning was about 500MB. after a i had to enable the swap